# Unable to connect to Postgres database via Golang

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, go

I am using Golang to connect to a Postgres DB instance.

When the code below is executed from an Amazon EC2 instance, the error is `not nil after sql.open()`.

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://username:mypassword@xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xx-xxxx-x.xxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxx/postgres?sslmode=disable")

    if err != nil {
        check(err)
        panic(err)
    }

    err = db.Ping()

    if err != nil {
        check(err)
        panic(err)
    }
```

However, when I run `db.Ping()` it doesn't do anything. The code after `db.ping()` doesn't seem to be executed. After a while I get `getsockopt: connection timed out` in the terminal window.

What could be the problem? Also even when I use the wrong password, the error is still `not nil`.

Comment: It can't connect.  Can you ping that other machine from the same EC2 instance?  Can you try a different pgsql client from the same EC2 instance?  Double check your parameters and setup.

Comment: @GuySirton- I cant seem to ping my ec2 or my Database instance from my machine. I am able to connect to the Database instance using PgAdmin from my mac

Comment: Ping protocol is normally disabled in AWS Security Groups. If your database is running on an Amazon EC2 instance and you wish to enable Ping, add `ICMP` to your Inbound Security Group.

Comment: Just before `db.Ping()`, try `_, err := db.Exec("SELECT 1")`, then check `err` whether it is `nil` or not. If it is not nil, perhaps `Ping()` doesn't act as what we think.